# Что это за UI элемент?

Tags: java, android, ui, bottom-sheet

Подскажите, что за UI элемент используется в WhatsApp (а именно, там где Documents, Camera, ...), это BottomSheet, только его расположили вверху? Или это что-то другое?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не юзал ватсап, обьясните как и когда он появляется? когда кликаешь на скрепку в тулбаре? выдвигается сверху?

Comment: @СергейГрушин Да, именно там!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DialogFragment + RevealEffect. Причем как был классический баг, так они его не исправили. При dispatch touch DialogFragment анимация может стартовать несколько раз, зависит от количества нажатий, пройдя свою duration, обрывается. Смотрится не ок.

Comment: А какие есть альтернативы сделать такое же, но без багов? Что бы смотрелось ок.

Comment: Да не... баг это их ошибка, причем классическая, как я и написал. Это очень легко исправить, видимо просто никто им еще не сообщил, а сами не заметили. Можете сделать аналогично, можно сделать с помощью popup, можно сделать с помощью доп слоя и скрыть его, или с toolbarLayout . Два последних будут отличаться, по back и front реализации.